# on a scholarship vs. on scholarship

Tags: indefinite-article, zero-article

Example ([These cramped Moscow dorms provide a rare glimpse into college life in Russia](http://www.businessinsider.com/dormitories-in-moscow-russia-2015-8)):

1:

> Ndlovu, who attends the university **on a scholarship**, pays $10 a month for his room. "It's cheap. That's for sure," he told Dumont.

2:

> Nigerian students Christopher Onoja, top, 22, and Issac Ismaila, bottom, 24, both came to Russia **on a scholarship**. “Honestly, I don’t like anything about this place because the rooms are full of roaches and bedbugs.

3:

> According to Dumont, rooms shared between three to four people are generally around $50 a month per person if the students are not **on scholarship**.

The same news article, but different grammar. Which one is correct though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct. But `on a scholarship` implies a specific scholarship while `on scholarship` describes a state. From these examples, you can see they use `on a scholarship` when describing specific students but they use `on scholarship` to describe the general state of a non-specified student.

Also, the word "scholarship" as used in `on scholarship` would be considered uncountable like the word "money". It is not necessarily referring to one scholarship as `on a scholarship` suggests.

Comment: It appears that 'scholarship' when used without an article can be considered uncountable, compare with "money".

Comment: Good point @VictorBazarov,  I will add to my answer

Comment: Scholarship is always a countable noun when it means the amount granted to a student to pay for his education.